# Checking pairs in a list?

Tags: python, list

Basically I have a program which will take a number and factor it down to the smallest number, being 2, 3, 5, 7, and so on. I'm having trouble figuring out how to check if there are one or multiple pairs of numbers inside of a list. For example.

```
    myList = [1,1,1,4,5,6,6,3,3,1]
```

in myList, there are four 1's which would be two pairs of two. Pairs then need to be thrown into another list but instead of adding both numbers making it a pair it only needs to have one of those numbers of the pair.

For example:

```
    myList = [1,1,1,4,5,6,6,3,3,1]
    doubles = [1,1,6,3]
```

So, there are four ones. Which in turn make two pairs of two, which would add into a list, but only one number needs to be added to a list representing a pair.

Comment: Does the order need to be preserved? Also, should the order be according to leading item of each pair or trailing? Specifically, is `1, 6, 3, 1` a valid answer?

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/2cea95b4f2bf1f34a3a9488238bf0243) is some code I wrote that finds all the prime factors (and their powers) of a positive integer and thence all the factors of that number.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to qarma's first solution, but it avoids the double `for` loop.

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 3, 1, 7, 7, 7]
doubles = []
for k, v in Counter(my_list).items():
    doubles.extend([k] * (v // 2))

print(doubles)
```

**output**

```
[1, 1, 6, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
>>> myList = [1,1,1,4,5,6,6,3,3,1]
>>> mySet = set()
>>> doubles = []
>>> for i in myList:
...     if i in mySet:
...         doubles.append(i)
...         mySet.remove(i)
...     else:
...         mySet.add(i)
... 
>>> doubles
[1, 6, 3, 1]
```

Note - This doesn't preserve the order you seem to have expected in your question, i.e. `[1, 1, 6, 3]`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you adapt this to remove the pairs out of the myList list?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want, the request isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

#### simple solution

```
[k for k, v in collections.Counter([1,1,1,4,5,6,6,3,3,1]).items() for _i in range(v // 2)]
[1, 1, 3, 6]
```

`Counter` is a kind of a dict, thus doesn't keep insertion order. Also, it compresses input, so for example, input like `1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1` is guaranteed to result in either `1, 1, 3` or `3, 1, 1` and never `1, 3, 1`.

#### more complex

```
In [7]: def pairs(s):
   ...:     queue = set()
   ...:     for i in s:
   ...:         if i in queue:
   ...:             yield i
   ...:             queue.remove(i)
   ...:         else:
   ...:             queue.add(i)
   ...:

In [8]: list(pairs([1,1,1,4,5,6,6,3,3,1]))
Out[8]: [1, 6, 3, 1]
```

This, preserves order of pairs, but pairs are ordered according to last item in a pair, e.g. `1, 9, 9, 1` becomes `9, 1`.

#### even more complex

```
In [12]: def pairs(s):
    ...:     incomplete = dict()
    ...:     done = []
    ...:     for i, v in enumerate(s):
    ...:         if v in incomplete:
    ...:             done.append((incomplete[v], v))
    ...:             del incomplete[v]
    ...:         else:
    ...:             incomplete[v] = i
    ...:     return [v[1] for v in sorted(done)]
    ...:
    ...:

In [13]: pairs([1,1,1,4,5,6,6,3,3,1])
Out[13]: [1, 1, 6, 3]
```

Here, original position of first element of each pair is kept as a value in the `incomplete` dict, which allows to reconstruct original order according to first item in a pair.

Answer (score 0):

using `defaultdictionary`

```
from collections import defaultdict
def func(lis):
    dic = defaultdict(int)
    for i in lis:
        dic[i]+=1
    list1 =[]
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if v>=2:
            list1.append([k]*(v//2))
    return list1    
myList = [1,1,1,4,5,6,6,3,3,1]
data =   [j for i in func(myList) for j in i]
print(data)
# output 
# [1,1,6,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

myList = [1,1,1,4,5,6,6,3,3,1]

dupes = Counter({k: v // 2 for k, v in Counter(myList).items()})
sorted(dupes.elements())
# [1, 1, 3, 6]
```